# JSON - get the values

Tags: jquery, json

JSON

```
  {
          "items": 
          [
            {
              "name": "Project title",
              "id": 16,
              "image": "\u002fimages\u002fdefault.png",
            },
            {
              "name": "Project title",
              "id": 25,
              "image": "\xxx",

            },
     ]
    }
```

JQquery

```
var getDataUrl = '/data';

$.ajax({
    url: getDataUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function( response ){
      console.log(response + 'get?');
      $.each(response, function() {
        console.log(response.name + 'get?');
    });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log( error)
    }
  });
```

Trying to get the responses' value to print but not sure why it is not displaying name. I need to get name, id and image but for now test and see if name is displayed...

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant to do this:

```
$.each(response.items, function() {
    console.log(this.name + 'get?');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `response` to `response.items`

```
success: function(response){
    $.each(response.items, function(i,v) {
        console.log(v.name + 'get?');
    });
}
```

Documentation : [**http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: before it was console.log(response.name + 'get?'); lol u have changed.anyways +1

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is:

```
jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
```

In your example you need to change your code like this:

```
$.each(response.items, function(i, v) {
    console.log(v.name + 'get?');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your success function try:

```
$.each(response.items, function(i,v) {
    console.log(v.name + 'get?');
});
```

Also, double check that you have valid JSON.  I think it is choking on the backslashes in your strings.  You can validate at a site like http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I know and i only copy a few lines and paste. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

First check the JSON Payload,i guess one comma is extra before']'.

Function should be like this...

```
$.each(response.items, function(i, j) {
    console.log(response.items[i].name);
});​
```